# Post to blogoverflow from desktop blogging app?

Tags: discussion, blog-overflow

Is it possible to post to a Stack Exchange blog from a desktop blogging app? How?

I'm personally most interested in posting from MS Word, because that's where my source material is already held, but am open to other [Wordpress recommended programs](http://en.support.wordpress.com/apps/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Blogoverflow is standard WordPress - just give your desktop blogging app the correct credentials and it should work without any issues. I haven't used MS Word for anything like this (to me it is a word processor with badly implemented integration with **anything**, including other MS products) so I would try one of the other programs on that list.

Personally, however, I wouldn't bother. It is so simple to just paste your content into WordPress directly.

Comment: I tried setting up Live Writer, but it asks for username and password credentials for logging in. *.blogoverflow is set to only allow OpenID. Also pasting not so simple for me. The experience which prompted the question was spending 15 minutes removing extra carriage returns and re-adding heading styles and so on to pasted content, and still having pictures to go.